# Exoplayer Analytics, Accurate way of getting analytics

Tags: android, google-analytics, analytics, exoplayer

Is there any accurate way of getting analytics from Exoplayer ? I want to get player analytics which can track total tracking time, exclude seeked track and all ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Analytics on ExoPlayer depends on the ExoPlayer version s well. Some basic analytics can be done via ExoPlayer's EventListener Callbacks itself. To get accurate data analytical data add event listener as per your need: available listeners are

1. EventListener: Provides ExoPlayer's general event callbacks
2. AudioRendererEventListener(deprecated now with V2.9.+). So better
   use AudioListener.
3. VideoRendererEventListener (deprecated now with V2.9.+). So better
   use VideoListener.
4. AnalyticsListener: Available With ExoPlayer V2.9.+ it has most of
   the available ExoPlayer callbacks. So it can be best suited as per
   you need.

In all you can use available callbacks provided by Exoplayer and get the required analytical data like, total tracking time, seek event data, bandwidth, bitrate, etc.

Comment: hi can you share sample code for this looking to add analytics to exo player

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by hooking up to the event callbacks ExoPlayer gives you and measuring these things yourself. You then need to send them to your backend and store/aggregate the data there over time.

An alternative would be to use a Video Analytics Solution that handles all of these things for you automatically like [Bitmovin Analytics](https://bitmovin.com/video-analytics/) or [Mux Data](https://mux.com/data).

*(Disclosure: I work for Bitmovin)*